# Is there a pathing algorithm that instead of finding a path from point A to point B, it returns a path that covers the whole map?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I'm looking for a pathing algorithm that finds a path that instead of being the common A to B algorithm, it finds a path that covers the whole map (for example, snaking through shelves in a store)

I tried making one myself but it was extremely inefficient and didn't branch out very far.

Any ideas or resources I could use?

Comment: Btw, are you working on the same problem as this user? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221603/most-area-covered-pathfinding-algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally quite hard to find "reasonable" paths that visit all locations before ending up somewhere. The ideal path you'd like is called a *Hamiltonian path* and, unfortunately, [no one knows how to find Hamiltonian paths efficiently in the general case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem). You'll probably need to either be content with weird paths that do a lot of retracing of steps or to accept paths that don't visit all locations before ending up at the destination.

Comment: Thanks, efficiency isn't my first prioritiy so this is fine.

Answer (score 3):

By "finding a path that covers the whole map," I'm going to assume you mean that starting at node A, you want to traverse *every* node before finishing at B.

You're essentially trying to find a Hamiltonian path for your graph with start and end nodes at A and B respectively. This problem is NP-complete, meaning that there is no computationally feasible algorithm that we currently know of for solving it (and we suspect, in fact, that there *is* no such algorithm).

The brute force solution is to branch out from A and try *every* path, hoping to find one that touches every node once and also ends at B. Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to do a whole lot better than that without modifying the constraints of the problem you're trying to solve.